# Exchange 2007 - One server set-up

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, exchange-2007

I'm trying to set up Exchange 2007 with just one server (not the Transport + Hub configuration, just a Hub).

I installed the server with the Hub Role, and it's not accepting SMTP. I changed SMTP so that it relays all emails (it's just an internal server for only internal mails).

When I send to `username@mydomain` in OCW, it works fine. When I send to the same email address via SMTP, it goes to the `badmail` folder.

What did I miss in the Hub set-up?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an internet send connector
2. Enable anonymous connections on the SMTP receive connector

Answer (score 0):

When you first install Exchange, it is setup to expect mail to come from an Edge Transport Server, to configure it so that it is a single server setup there are some changes you need to make. I would suggest following the steps in [this article](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/11/17/431555.aspx) to get things setup how you want.

Answer (score -1):

you need to make sure you're allowing port 25 on your receive connector. You can use the GUI tools to track the message and it might give you some clues as to what's happening as well.